# Need to calculate Year wise sum in the desired output format below, but I am getting column wise data

Tags: sql

I just need to know that how can I get the row wise- year totals.
Here is my code and need to get the below expected result :

```
SELECT /*+parallel(v,32) +parallel(mm,32) +parallel(c,32) */
    'BUS' VEH_TYPE,
    MM.MAKE_MO,
     SUM (CASE WHEN SUBSTR (V.YEAR_Val, 1, 4) = '1990' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        AS FY1990,
     SUM (CASE WHEN SUBSTR (V.YEAR_VAL, 1, 4) = '1991' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        AS FY1991,
     SUM (CASE WHEN SUBSTR (V.YEAR_VAL, 1, 4) = '1992' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        AS FY1992,
     SUM (CASE WHEN SUBSTR (V.YEAR_VAL, 1, 4) = '1993' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        AS FY1993,
     SUM (CASE WHEN SUBSTR (V.YEAR_VAL, 1, 4) = '1994' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        AS FY1994,
     SUM (CASE WHEN SUBSTR (V.YEAR_VAL, 1, 4) = '1995' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        AS FY1995,
     COUNT (MM.MAKE_MO) Total_Count
     FROM VEHICLE V, MAKE mm, CATEGORY c
     WHERE C.MAKE_MO = mm.MAKE_MO
     AND c.CATEGORY_CD = v.CATEGORY_CD
     AND V.p_MONTH BETWEEN '199001' AND '199501' --using this as data is huge 
     AND C.TYPE_CODE=01
     AND MM.VEH_CODE='B' 
GROUP BY 'BUS,'MM.MAKE_MO, V.YEAR_Val
ORDER BY V.YEAR_Val;
```

This is the Expected Result :

```
VEH TYPE  YEAR MODEL     TOTAL   
-------   -----        --------  
Bus       1990        7,808,658  
Bus       1991        5,474,809  
Bus       1992        54,839,221  
Bus       1993        54,680,000  
Bus       1994        15,000,000
Bus       1995        17,899,668
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample data? We see what transformations you're performing but without any input we can't make any assumptions as to what's in your `VEHICLE`, `MAKE`, and `CATEGORY` tables.

Comment: And what are you getting now? What is your question?

Comment: It would be helpful with the input along with the output (makes replication easier). Also, try (with words) to describe what it is you want to achieve.

Comment: First, "`FROM VEHICLE V, MAKE mm, CATEGORY c`" >>> Please, please, please don't use the older comma-syntax JOINs. Use actual ANSI-syle JOINs, It will make your life _MUCH_ easier. Also, "`ORDER BY 2`" >>> Using ordinal position can make for hard to debug issues. From there, you're SELECTing 8 columns but only show 3 in your expected output. Please provide more information as to what you have and what you're trying to do. Something like sqlfiddle.com or dbfiddle.uk will help you put together a good, usable example for others to help with.

Comment: Are you storing dates in a char/varchar column?!? Use proper date data type!

Comment: Also, "`...BETWEEN '199001' AND '199501'`"  >>> I see what you're trying to do, and it "technically" works, however you are type-converting `199001` to a string and doing a `BETWEEN` when it would be just as easy to leave them as numbers, unless they are stored in your database as strings, then you might get some unexpected results. That's essentially the same as `...BETWEEN 'a' AND 'z'`. You'd be better off all around if they were integers.

Answer (score 0):

This was way too long for a comment. After unwinding this query, it appears that you are simply trying to get a count of 'Bus' vehicles by model year (with ALL vehicles in the `VEHICLE` table are being labeled 'Bus'). If that's the case, you can simplify your query a lot.

```
SELECT VEH_TYPE
    , theYear AS YEAR_MODEL
    , COUNT(*) AS TOTAL
FROM (
    SELECT 'BUS' AS VEH_TYPE
        , SUBSTR(V.YEAR_Val,1,4) AS theYear
    FROM VEHICLE V
    INNER JOIN CATEGORY c ON v.CATEGORY_CD = c.CATEGORY_CD
        AND C.TYPE_CODE='01'
    INNER JOIN MAKE mm ON c.MAKE_MO = mm.MAKE_MO
        AND MM.VEH_CODE='B' 
    WHERE V.p_MONTH BETWEEN '199001' AND '199501'
) s1
WHERE theYear IN ('1990','1991','1992','1993','1994','1995')
GROUP BY theYear
```

You may not need the `WHERE` clause if your vehicle years are only 1990-1995. And your JOINed tables don't appear to be doing anything other than limiting your `VEHICLE` table if there are no `CATEGORY_CD` matches in `VEHICLE` and `CATEGORY`, and if there are no `MAKE_MO` matches in `MAKE` and `CATEGORY`. If you were filtering for a specific column from `CATEGORY` or `MAKE`, or you had orphaned records in `VEHICLE`, then you'd want to add those JOINs back in. Otherwise, I don't think they're really doing anything.

Note that `SUBSTR(V.YEAR_Val,1,4)` will exclude any index you have on `V.YEAR_Val`, and if that's a column you need regularly, or if there are a lot of `VEHICLE` records, you may need to split that value into its own column.

Comment: @Shawn- I need where to add other filter conditions that I have added, i did not wanted to pollute the code so didnt give much filter details.I just want to know that how do I get the row wise year totals for this query. Currently I am having the column totals.

Comment: @developer_07 I'm not sure what you mean. I updated my code to add the JOIN criteria back in. And just FYI, including details that will impact results isn't polluting the code, but needed to properly answer the question. What do you mean by "row-wise year totals" and "column totals"? Do you want the totals for the years, like in your query? If so, what is the main totals column counting? Please update your expected output if it is different. Also, if you can build some sample data, that would help. SQLFiddle.com works pretty well for something like that.